# How to subscribe on array changes using RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a simple array:

`var similarObjects: [Objects] = []`

How I can see his changes after:

`similarObjects = someArray`

I try: (result: next -> complete)

```
_ = Observable.just(similarObjects)
     .subscribe({ event in
         return print(event.element)
     })
```

Comment: in Swift its very easy to observe object changes. so you want it in Swift or RxSwift ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to observe changes for your similarObjects , you have to make it of type Observable...

So for example you declare similarObjects as follow:

`var similarObjects: PublishSubject<[Objects]> = PublishSubject<[Objects]>()`

And you can subscribe to it by:

```
similarObjects
   .asObservable()
   .subscribe(onNext:{
         print($0)
   }
```

And when you want to assign it a value, you can use onNext operator

Example:

```
similarObjects.onNext(someArray)
```

By calling onNext, print($0) statement will be executed, make sure to subscribe before calling onNext to your Subject..

Answer (score 2):

Probably the built-in `didSet` solution is the best, but rxswift can handle this by using any of `*Subject` types.

For example, if you choose `PublishSubject` (starts empty and only emits new elements to subscribers):

```
let similarObjectsSubject = PublishSubject<[Objects]>()
```

Pass value to subject:

```
similarObjectsSubject.onNext(similarObjects)
```

And handle changes somewhere in code:

```
similarObjectsSubject.subscribe(onNext: { objects in
     // ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by making similarObjects as a relay, like

```
 //create a relay object for the array
    let similarObjects: BehaviorRelay<[Objects]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [])

    //subscribe to the chnages
    _ = similarObjects.subscribe(onNext: { (similarObjects) in
        //you will get them here
    }, onError: { (error) in
        //error
    }, onCompleted: {
        //completed
    }) {
        //do something when disposed
    }


    //now when you set the array like this
    similarObjects.accept(someArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BehaviorRelay` to get event when value is manipulated like Add, Update, Delete or assign with new value to array.

```
  var similarObjects = BehaviorRelay<[Object]>(value: [])

  similarObjects.subscribe(onNext: { (array) in
        print(array)
  }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

  similarObjects.accept(someArray)
```

Comment: `Variable` is deprecated in new versions of RxSwift.